# How to spawn Multiple of the same SpriteNode at once?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I have 3 different obstacles which spawn randomly and get removed after 3 seconds, but if for example Obstacle1 is already spawned and the random Number tells the program to spawn another Obstacle1, I get a Error that says

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which
>   already has a parent"

heres the code of Obstacle1, the other two are almost the same just the names are different:
 `func createObst1() {
        self.addChild(obst1)
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -170), radius: circle.frame.size.height / 2 + obst1.frame.size.width / 2 - 4, startAngle: CGFloat(rad) * 2, endAngle:  CGFloat(rad) + CGFloat(M_PI * 2.5), clockwise: true)
        let follow = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: TimeInterval(roundDuration))
        obst1.isHidden = false
        let fadeOutInstant = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0)
        let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.3)
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.3)
        let pause = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.4)
        let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOutInstant, fadeIn, pause, fadeOut, remove])
        let group = SKAction.group([follow, sequence])
        obst1.run(group)
    }`

Do I have to create multiple Obstacle1 functions with the same Code in it or is there a other way do solve my problem?

Here's also the Code how I randomly spawn the Obstacles in case it helps: `func gameStarted() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(randomDelay), target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.obstSwitch), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }`

```
func obstSwitch() {
let rand = arc4random_uniform(3)    
switch rand{
case 0:
    createObst1()

case 1:
    createObst2()

case 2:
    createObst3()

default:
    break
    }
}
```

Comment: It is all about your code logic. Show what you have tried so far, so that somebody can suggest what to fix/change. By the way, your question doesn't follow SO rules, and it will be likely put on hold until it meets this site's [standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: I would start with...Node can have only one parent. So you have to create new sprite each time. Also using that Timer will bite you in the future probably because it doesn't have a pause feature, so you will have a dance  with  invalidating timers / re-creating them / storing time passed etc. Use `SKAction` because it is automatically paused when node is paused.

Comment: Ok, so how do I create a new Sprite which is the same as Obstacle1 and whats an alternative to the Timer?

Comment: Checkout my answer. I think I covered everything you were interested about, so you will probably easily modify your code to something like this. You can copy and paste this code to see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let obstacles = [
            SKSpriteNode(color:.brown, size:CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)),
            SKSpriteNode(color:.white, size:CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)),
            SKSpriteNode(color:.black, size:CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)),
        ]


    func getRandomObstacle(fromArray array:[SKSpriteNode])->SKSpriteNode{

        return array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]
    }


    func spawnObstacle(atPosition position:CGPoint) {

        if let obstacle = getRandomObstacle(fromArray: obstacles).copy() as? SKSpriteNode {

            obstacle.position = position

            //apply action that fade out and remove the node after 3 seconds

            let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 3)
            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut,remove])

            obstacle.run(sequence, withKey: "aKey")

            addChild(obstacle)

        }

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            spawnObstacle(atPosition: location)
        } 
    }  
}
```

This code basically  spawn a copy of an random obstacle on every tap. Because you make copies, there are no worries about the error you are getting currently.

To use `SKAction` to spawn nodes, as you said, as an alternative to Timer you would create an action sequence with two elements, a wait action, and a block that spawns a node. This is how action sequence might look like:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        //Setup scene and nodes

        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)

        let spawn = SKAction.run({[unowned self] in

            //calculate obstalce initial position here, eg. randomize it

            let spawnLocation = //...
            self.spawnObstacle(atPosition: spawnLocation)
        })

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
        let loop = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
        run(loop , withKey:"spawning")

    }
```

Comment: I found another way to spawn multiple of the same SpriteNode at once but thanks for the alternative to the timer! :)

Comment: @LukasDomeisen Well, something like using update: method could work as well. But I personally prefer actions. You can post your solution if you like for the future readers. You can accept your own answer as well :)