# Is there a SKAction to call a Function?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I have a function which creates a Obstacle and i want to make a Sequence with two elements: random delay which is a random number, and call Obstacle function. I first did this with the Timer but it would be much easier with Actions.

Comment: Yes. Check out `SKAction.run(...)`

Comment: Did even look at my previous answer? : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41785775/3402095 Look at the sequence and a spawn block.

Comment: Ohh now i see it, sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to spawn Multiple of the same SpriteNode at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784340/how-to-spawn-multiple-of-the-same-spritenode-at-once)

Answer (score 2):

`SKAction.run()` then just put whatever function you want in the closures.